# Add a class (or attribute) if not already there

Tags: jquery

How would I add an attribute to an element if that element does not already have that attribute?

```
if (' this does not have class=selected') {

    $(this).addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: Do you mean class specifically, or any attribute? Because you can call .addClass() as many times as you want.

Comment: And that won't add a duplicate?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a duplicate.  Either an element has a class or it doesn't; if it has the same class more than once, from the perspective of Javascrcipt and the DOM, it has the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking specifically about classes, then just go ahead and add it. If it already exists, it won't be added twice.

```
$(this).addClass('selected'); // will only add the class if it doesn't exist
```

I doubt that first testing for the class would be any more efficient.

***live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/2sLd5/

Answer (score 7):

```
if(!$(this).attr('name')) {
   $(this).attr('name', 'value');
}
```

that ought to do it.

Comment: I just tried this as is exactly what I want but couldn't get it to work if(!$(this).attr('placeholder')) {
   $(this).attr('placeholder', 'c');
}

Comment: This question has an incorrect title.  This answer correctly answers the question as it is stated in the title.  If the title is ever corrected, this answer will appear to be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery documentation is your friend! :)
http://api.jquery.com/category/css/

You are probably looking for the HasClass

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

```
$('#mydiv').hasClass('foo')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute not selector. This works not only for classes but for any attribute

```
if($('#elemid[class!="myclass"]').length) {
    $('#elemid').addClass('otherClass');
}
```

Of course as mentioned before if you want to add the class your checking against, just add it. There is no harm in that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to check and see if the class is already present before adding the class.  Looking through the jQuery source (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js, search for `addClass`), it appears that `addClass` will do nothing if the class is already present.  Therefore, there's no point to checking first.